# NRF24L01 is not sending valid data

Tags: arduino

I have a problem with NRF24L01
I'm building a weather station and I ran into a problem, I can't send the correct value from each sensor to the receiver. The values in the char are sending correctly but the float value is not, I keep getting the value 656677.37

Here is the transmitter code

```
//DallasTemperature
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

//DHT11
#include <DHT.h>

//BMP280
#include <Wire.h>
#include "i2c.h"
#include "i2c_BMP280.h"

#include <MQ135.h>

//NRF24l01 pn ln
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>



//============================================[Pin Definitions]=============================================
#define MQ135_PIN A1
#define DHT_PIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 3
#define LDR_PIN A0
#define RAIN_PIN A2



//============================================[Global defines]=============================================
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DHT dht(DHT_PIN, DHTTYPE);
BMP280 bmp280;
MQ135 mq135_sensor(MQ135_PIN);
RF24 radio(9, 10); // CE, CSN



//============================================[Global variables]=============================================
float temp_DALLAS;

float humidity_DHT;
float temperature_DHT;
float hic;

float temperature_BMP;
float pascal_BMP;


float rzero_MQ135;
float correctedRZero_MQ135;
float resistance_MQ135;
float ppm_MQ135;
float correctedPPM_MQ135;

#define MAX_ADC_READING 1023
#define ADC_REF_VOLTAGE 5.0
#define REF_RESISTANCE 5030  // measure this for best results
#define LUX_CALC_SCALAR 12518931
#define LUX_CALC_EXPONENT -1.405
int ldrRawData;
float resistorVoltage, ldrVoltage;
float ldrResistance;
float ldrLux;

int rainRawData;



const byte address[6] = "00001";
#define nodechar 20
#define typechar 20
//#define valuechar 20
//#define unitchar 20

struct Template {
  char node[nodechar];
  char type[typechar];
  //char value[valuechar] = "\0";
  //char unit[unitchar];
  float value;
};Template myStruct;

unsigned int h_old = 0;
unsigned int h_new = 0;
unsigned int t_old = 0;
unsigned int t_new = 0;
unsigned int hic_old = 0;
unsigned int hic_new = 0;

unsigned int pbmp_old = 0;
unsigned int pbmp_new = 0;
unsigned int tbmp_old = 0;
unsigned int tbmp_new = 0;

unsigned int rzMQ135_old = 0;
unsigned int rzMQ135_new = 0;
unsigned int crzMQ135_old = 0;
unsigned int crzMQ135_new = 0;
unsigned int rMQ135_old = 0;
unsigned int rMQ135_new = 0;
unsigned int ppmMQ135_old = 0;
unsigned int ppmMQ135_new = 0;
unsigned int cppmMQ135_old = 0;
unsigned int cppmMQ135_new = 0;


unsigned int tdallas_old = 0;
unsigned int tdallas_new = 0;

unsigned int ldr_old = 0;
unsigned int ldr_new = 0;

unsigned int rain_old = 0;
unsigned int rain_new = 0;



void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);

    dht.begin();

    Serial.print("Probe BMP280: ");
    if(bmp280.initialize()) Serial.println("Sensor found");
    else Serial.println("Sensor missing");
    

    bmp280.setEnabled(0);
    bmp280.triggerMeasurement();

    Serial.print("Locating devices...");
    sensors.begin();
    Serial.print("Found ");
    Serial.print(sensors.getDeviceCount(), DEC);
    Serial.println(" devices.");

    if (!radio.begin()) Serial.println(F("radio hardware is not responding!!"));
    else Serial.println(F("radio hardware is responding!!"));
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    //radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
    radio.openWritingPipe(address);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
    radio.stopListening();

    String stringOne2 = "1;Meteo";
    stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.node, nodechar);
}


void loop(){
    humidity_DHT = dht.readHumidity();
    temperature_DHT = dht.readTemperature();

    hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(temperature_DHT, humidity_DHT, false);


    bmp280.awaitMeasurement();
    bmp280.getTemperature(temperature_BMP);
    bmp280.getPressure(pascal_BMP);

    static float meters, metersold;
    bmp280.getAltitude(meters);
    metersold = (metersold * 10 + meters)/11;

    bmp280.triggerMeasurement();


    rzero_MQ135 = mq135_sensor.getRZero();
    correctedRZero_MQ135 = mq135_sensor.getCorrectedRZero(temperature_DHT, humidity_DHT);
    resistance_MQ135 = mq135_sensor.getResistance();
    ppm_MQ135 = mq135_sensor.getPPM();
    correctedPPM_MQ135 = mq135_sensor.getCorrectedPPM(temperature_DHT, humidity_DHT);

    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    // method 2 - faster
    temp_DALLAS = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);


    ldrRawData = analogRead(LDR_PIN);
    resistorVoltage = (float)ldrRawData / MAX_ADC_READING * ADC_REF_VOLTAGE;
    ldrVoltage = ADC_REF_VOLTAGE - resistorVoltage;
    ldrResistance = ldrVoltage/resistorVoltage * REF_RESISTANCE;
    ldrLux = LUX_CALC_SCALAR * pow(ldrResistance, LUX_CALC_EXPONENT);

    rainRawData = analogRead(RAIN_PIN);
    rainRawData = 1024 - rainRawData;




    /*Serial.print(F("Humidity: "));
    Serial.print(humidity_DHT);
    Serial.print(F("%  Temperature: "));
    Serial.print(temperature_DHT);
    Serial.print(F("°C "));
    Serial.print(F(" Heat index: "));
    Serial.print(hic);
    Serial.print(F("°C    "));


    Serial.print(" HeightPT1: ");
    Serial.print(metersold);
    Serial.print(" m; Height: ");
    Serial.print(meters);
    Serial.print(" Pressure: ");
    Serial.print(pascal_BMP);
    Serial.print(" Pa; T: ");
    Serial.print(temperature_BMP);
    Serial.print(" C    ");

    
    Serial.print("MQ135 RZero: ");
    Serial.print(rzero_MQ135);
    Serial.print(" Corrected RZero: ");
    Serial.print(correctedRZero_MQ135);
    Serial.print(" Resistance: ");
    Serial.print(resistance_MQ135);
    Serial.print(" PPM: ");
    Serial.print(ppm_MQ135);
    Serial.print("ppm");
    Serial.print(" Corrected PPM: ");
    Serial.print(correctedPPM_MQ135);
    Serial.print("ppm    ");


    Serial.print("Temp C: ");
    Serial.print(temp_DALLAS);


    Serial.print("    LDR Raw Data: ");
    Serial.print(ldrRawData);
    Serial.print(" LDR Voltage: ");
    Serial.print(ldrVoltage);
    Serial.print(" volts LDR Resistance: ");
    Serial.print(ldrResistance);
    Serial.print(" Ohms LDR Illuminance: ");
    Serial.print(ldrLux);
    Serial.print(" lux    Rain:");
    Serial.println(rainRawData);*/


    h_new = humidity_DHT;
    if(h_new != h_old){
        //myStruct.type = 1;
        String stringOne = "HUMIDITY_DHT";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "%";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = h_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        h_old = h_new;
    }

    t_new = temperature_DHT;
    if(t_new != t_old){
       // myStruct.type = 2;
        String stringOne = "TEMP_DHT";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "°C";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = t_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        t_old = t_new;
    }

    hic_new = hic;
    if(hic_new != hic_old){
        //myStruct.type = 3;
        String stringOne = "HIC_DHT";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "°C";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = hic_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        hic_old = hic_new;
    }


    pbmp_new = pascal_BMP;
    if(pbmp_new != pbmp_old){
        //myStruct.type = 4;
        String stringOne = "PASCAL_BMP";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "Pa";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = pbmp_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        pbmp_old = pbmp_new;
    }

    tbmp_new = temperature_BMP;
    if(tbmp_new != tbmp_old){
        //myStruct.type = 5;
        String stringOne = "TEMP_BMP";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "°C";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = tbmp_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        tbmp_old = tbmp_new;
    }


    rzMQ135_new = rzero_MQ135;
    if(rzMQ135_new != rzMQ135_old){
       // myStruct.type = 6;
        String stringOne = "RZ_MQ135";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "raw";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = rzMQ135_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        rzMQ135_old = rzMQ135_new;
    }

    crzMQ135_new = correctedRZero_MQ135;
    if(crzMQ135_new != crzMQ135_old){
        //myStruct.type = 7;
        String stringOne = "CRZ_MQ135";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "raw";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = crzMQ135_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        crzMQ135_old = crzMQ135_new;
    }

    rMQ135_new = resistance_MQ135;
    if(rMQ135_new != rMQ135_old){
        //myStruct.type = 8;
        String stringOne = "R_MQ135";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "R";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = rMQ135_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        rMQ135_old = rMQ135_new;
    }

    ppmMQ135_new = ppm_MQ135;
    if(ppmMQ135_new != ppmMQ135_old){
        //myStruct.type = 9;
        String stringOne = "PPM_MQ135";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "ppm";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = ppmMQ135_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        ppmMQ135_old = ppmMQ135_new;
    }

    cppmMQ135_new = correctedPPM_MQ135;
    if(cppmMQ135_new != cppmMQ135_old){
        //myStruct.type = 10;
        String stringOne = "CPPM_MQ135";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "ppm";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = cppmMQ135_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        cppmMQ135_old = cppmMQ135_new;
    }


    tdallas_new = temp_DALLAS;
    if(tdallas_new != tdallas_old){
        //myStruct.type = 10;
        String stringOne = "Temp_Dallas";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "°C";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = tdallas_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        tdallas_old = tdallas_new;
    }


    ldr_new = ldrLux;
    if(ldr_new != ldr_old){
        //myStruct.type = 11;
        String stringOne = "LDR";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "lux";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = ldr_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        ldr_old = ldr_new;
    }


    rain_new = rainRawData;
    if(rain_new != rain_old){
       // myStruct.type = 12;
        String stringOne = "RAIN";
        stringOne.toCharArray(myStruct.type, typechar);

        /*String stringOne2 = "%";
        stringOne2.toCharArray(myStruct.unit, unitchar);*/

        myStruct.value = rain_new;
        radio.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        rain_old = rain_new;
    }


    delay(500);
}
```

Here is the receiver code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define WIRE Wire
Adafruit_SSD1306 display = Adafruit_SSD1306(128, 32, &WIRE);

RF24 radio(9,10); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";

#define nodechar 20
#define typechar 20
//#define unitchar 20
//#define valuechar 20

struct MyStruct{
  char node[nodechar];
  char type[typechar];
  //char unit[unitchar];
  float value;
};

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("OLED FeatherWing test");
    // SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC = generate display voltage from 3.3V internally
    display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);

    if(!radio.begin()) Serial.println(F("radio hardware is not responding!!"));
    else Serial.println(F("radio hardware is responding!!"));

    radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    radio.startListening();

    display.display();

    // Clear the buffer.
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.display();
}

void loop(){
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setTextSize(1);
    display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    display.print("IP: 10.0.0.243\n");

    if(radio.available()){
        MyStruct myStruct;
        radio.read(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
        //char text[32] = "";
        //radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
        Serial.print(myStruct.node);
        Serial.print(" - ");
        Serial.print(myStruct.type);
        Serial.print(" - ");
        Serial.println(myStruct.value);
        //Serial.print(" - ");
        //Serial.println(myStruct.unit);
        

        //display.clearDisplay();
        //display.setTextSize(1);
        //display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(1,1);
        display.print("\nID: ");
        display.print(myStruct.node);
        display.print("\nType:");
        display.print(myStruct.type);
        display.print("\nValue:");
        display.println(myStruct.value);
        //display.println("Sending val #0");
        //display.setCursor(0,0);
        display.display(); // actually display all of the above
    }
}
```

I can't send the correct float value, without sending data I get the correct values from the sensors

Comment: Problem solved, NRF24L01 transfers max 32 bytes and my structure took over 40, I reduced the size of the structure and everything works

Comment: Feel free to create an answer yourself, and even mark it as solution. Better visible than your comment here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe struct alignment problem :
try this on each side :

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) MyStruct{
  char node[nodechar];
  char type[typechar];
  //char unit[unitchar];
  float value;
};
```